# JUnit test case for Action Class (Struts 2) when each method returns a model

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to JUnit and I need to write JUnit test cases for many methods like this. Any leads are much appreciated.Thanks

```java
public String screen() {

    ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest(
            Key1.Key2.Home.screenDisplay,
            Key1.Key2.serviceClass);
    ServiceResponse response = getService(request);
    someModel = new someModel();
    someModel = (someModel) response
            .getOutput(Key1.Key2.Home.Out);
    if (someModel != null) {

        someModel.setList(someModel.getList());

        setsomeModel(someModel);
    }
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   someModel = new someModel();
```

This line doesn't do anything in the end, since you overwrite `someModel` in the next line anyway.

In your case, you could, for example, use Mockito to spy your object and thus allow the getService() method to return something you control - assuming it is not private. If it is, then you'll have problems.

Just to show you, how it's done:

```
class ToTest {

    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println( methodB() );
    }

    String methodB() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

public class TestCase {

    @Test
    public void bla() {
        final ToTest x = Mockito.spy( new ToTest() );
        Mockito.when( x.methodB() ).thenReturn( "bar" );

        x.methodA(); // prints out "bar"

        Mockito.verify( x ).methodB();
    }    
}
```

If you return a mock from your getService() method, you can then verify that `setList` was called (ok, in your case you somehow make something strange by setting the same list) and you can verify on your spy object, that setsomeModel was called.